# Continue execution after multiple ListenableFutures return

Tags: java, guava

I have an application which accepts user commands to perform database lookups. I parse the commands/arguments and then iterate each one, calling a handler which takes the value and builds a query condition.

However, this process has been entirely synchronous until now. Each handler would execute and add the condition and after the loop was done I could execute the query.

Now, one of these handlers has to contact a remote server to convert some data which means it returns a `ListenableFuture`.

```
ListenableFuture<Profile> profile = getProfile("someUserName");

profile.addListener(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            query.addCondition(Condition.of("user.$id", MatchRule.EQUALS, profile.get().getUniqueId()));
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
           // handle
        }
    }
}, MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor());
```

I'm trying to determine the best way to ensure that I don't execute my query until this `ListenableFuture` has completed. Part of what's confusing me, is that I need to assume that there could be multiple pending requests.

For example if someone enters `p=user1,user2` we need to make two requests, so there will be two `ListenableFuture<Profile>`s pending.

Only once *both* have completed, can I execute the final query.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Futures.allAsList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList(java.lang.Iterable)) lets you take a bunch of `ListenableFutures` and get out one `ListenableFuture` that completes when all its inputs have completed and returns the list of results.  That sounds like what you need.